# crawling webpages with onclick attribute

Tags: python-2.7, onclick, scrapy

i try to scrawl one webpage, but its in italian language default, so i need to switch language to english.
this is piece of code in page:

```
<td class="lang">
    [<a href="#" class="active" onclick="return SwitchLang('it')">ita</a> | 
    <a href="#" onclick="return SwitchLang('en')">eng</a>]
</td>
```

i try to use scrapy for that, i read about FormRequest.from_response method, but i dont know, how exactly i have to use it. I try using formxpath.

My piece of code in spider is:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(
                        response,                  
                        formxpath='/td[@class="lang"]/a[2]', 
                        dont_click=False, 
                        callback=self.after_lang_change)
                   ]
```

but it get error:

```
raise ValueError('No <form> element found with %s' % formxpath)
exceptions.ValueError: No <form> element found with /td[@class="lang"]/a[2]
```

how can i 'click' and change language ?
thanks

Comment: You just cannot do it with scrapy. Could you show the url you are trying to scrape and whole code of your spider? There are some workarounds you can try.

Comment: i used Selenium for it and its working.